# Show the progress Dialog until load the data to List

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I developing the application where data loaded to ArrayList requires to 2/3 seconds. I want to show the progress of loading data to ArrayList.

I am using the AsyncTask for that. I execute this is on click of button and when ArrayList is fully loaded then it will passing to next activity via Intent.

Code Snippet as follows-

onClick of Button -

```
showList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {

      if (session.isOpened()) {

         if (friendID.size() == 0 && friendName.size() == 0) {

        new Async().execute();
      }
    }
});
```

Ansyc Task class are as follows -

```
class Async extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait for completion");
        dialog.setProgress(0);

        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync(session,
            new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

                            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users,
                            Response response) {

                 Iterator<GraphUser> iterator = users.iterator();
                 GraphUser graphUser = null;

                    friendID.clear();
                    friendName.clear();

                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            if (iterator != null) {
                                graphUser = iterator.next();

                                Log.d("Friend Information ",
                                        " friend ID " + graphUser.getId()
                                                + " friend Name "
                                                + graphUser.getName());

                                friendID.add(graphUser.getId());
                                friendName.add(graphUser.getName());

                                publishProgress(friendID.size());

                                Log.d("Friend Information ", " friendID= "
                                        + friendID.size() + " friendName "
                                        + friendName.size());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });

        dialog.dismiss();
        return "sucess";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FriendsList.class);

        Log.d("Checking the size ", "ID " + friendID.size() + " UserName "
                + friendName.size());

        /*
         * Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         * .show();
         */

        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("userID", friendID);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("userName", friendName);
        intent.putExtra("str", result);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        dialog.setProgress(values[0]);
        //dialog.incrementProgressBy(values[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

The error in Log Cat -

```
04-12 14:15:56.595: E/AndroidRuntime(15794): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-12 14:15:56.595: E/AndroidRuntime(15794): **java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()**

04-12 14:15:56.595: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)

04-12 14:15:56.595: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)

04-12 14:15:56.595: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)

04-12 14:15:56.595: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)

04-12 14:15:56.595: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)

04-12 14:15:56.595: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)

04-12 14:15:56.595: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)

04-12 14:15:56.595: E/AndroidRuntime(15794):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-12 14:15:56.595: E/AndroidRuntime(15794): **Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**
```

Comment: Hey thank you friend I got solution. **oncomplete()** method executed by a background thread: do not update the UI in this method.http://stackoverflow.com/a/8213857/2123594

Answer (score 1):

2 points:

1. Looks like your `Request.executeMyFriendsRequestAsync` is an async action so you just request some actions and quickly return from the `AsyncTask.doInBackground()`. So, with such a design the data loading itself happens later, when `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` has been already passed. You need to switch on a sycn API, so all friends data is loaded while being in `AsyncTask.doInBackground()`.
2. Call `dialog.dismiss();` inside of `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`

Comment: Thank you for replying...! But will you elaborate your answer please? I cant get where to do change in my code... Once again thx in advance